# uninstalling whatsapp

Tags: command-line, bash, google-chrome, webapps

I have installed WhatsApp by following these steps:

1. Type `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/whatsapp-webapp.desktop` in the Terminal.
2. Copy the following text to opened screen:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=WhatsApp
   GenericName=WhatsApp
   Comment=WhatsApp desktop webapp
   #Exec=webapp-container --store-session-cookies --webappUrlPatterns=https?://*.whatsapp.com/* --user-agent-string='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36' https://web.whatsapp.com %u
   Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true
   MimeType=text/plain;
   # If you want icon, type path of icon
   # Icon=
   Categories=Network;Application;
   Keywords=WhatsApp;webapp;
   X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=WhatsApp
   StartupWMClass=web.whatsapp.com
   ```
3. Finally, for keyboard shortcuts to open it, create:

   ```bash
   bash -c "wmctrl -xa web.whatsapp.com || /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/"
   ```

Now I want to **uninstall** this application. What are the steps to perform the uninstallation?

Comment: Simply delete the Desktop entry you made.

Comment: If you need an alternative app then try whatsdesk which is an unofficial whatsapp client for linux. It's available to download from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the `/usr/share/applications/whatsapp-webapp.desktop` file with the following commands:

```
cd /usr/share/applications/
sudo rm /whatsapp-webapp.desktop
```

whatsdesk is an unofficial WhatsApp client for Linux that can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo snap install whatdesk
```

To use WhatsApp on your computer:

1. Open WhatsApp on your phone.
2. Tap Menu **⋮** or Settings ⚙️ and select WhatsApp Web.
3. Point your phone to the QR code image.